# What can we say about the limit of : $O((n-1)/n)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, asymptotics

Let's say I want to compute :

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} O\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right)$$

Then can we say that to infty this is equal to $O(1)$ ? 
Because it could also mean that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ there is a constant $C_n$ such that : $\mid f\mid \leq C_n \cdot \frac{n-1}{n}$

And in the case where the sequence : $C_n$ is such that : $n = o(C_n)$
then we have : 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} O\left(\frac{n-1}{n}\right) = O(+\infty)$$

That's why I am wondering : when we say that a function $f$ is $O(\frac{n-1}{n})$ then does it mean : $\mid f\mid \leq C \cdot \frac{n-1}{n} \forall n$, or : $\forall n, \exists C_n$ such that $\mid f \mid \leq C_n \cdot \frac{n-1}{n}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when we say that a function $f$ is $O(\frac{n-1}{n})$ then does it mean : $\mid f\mid \leq C \cdot \frac{n-1}{n} \forall n$, or : $\forall n, \exists C_n$ such that $\mid f \mid \leq C_n \cdot \frac{n-1}{n}$ ?

Neither. It means $\exists n_0 \exists C$ such that $\forall n \ge n_0: |f| \le C \cdot \frac{n-1}{n}$.

$O$-notation is often abused, but I've never before seen $\lim_{n \to \infty} O(f(n))$. If that makes any sense at all, it's to disambiguate between the asymptotic behaviour for large $n$ and the asymptotic behaviour for small $n$.

Finally, observe that if $n > 0$ and $|f| \le C \cdot \frac{n-1}{n}$ then certainly $|f| \le C \cdot 1$, and we can indeed say that $f(n) \in O(1)$.

Comment: Thank you. Then if I have  sequence $(u_n)_{n \geq 1}$ such that : $u_n = O(\frac{1}{n})$ it means that $\exists C, \exists n_O$ such that : $\forall n \geq n_0 : \mid u_n \mid \leq C\cdot \frac{1}{n}$ so in particular : $\mid u_n \mid \to 0$. Moreover it also means that the notation $O$ is only true at $\infty$, so I can't say anything about $u_1$ ? Is verything I've said so far true ?

Comment: I wouldn't use the phrase "*is only true at $\infty$*". Talking about the notation being *true* can give the wrong idea. I would prefer to talk about what the notation *means* or *describes*. $O$ notation describes the behaviour *for large $n$* (although be careful: one of the more common abuses is to use it for small $n$, and in particular when you see $O(n^{-1})$ the context is often this inverted meaning). But you're correct to say that you can't say anything about $u_1$: the notation conceals the cutoff point.